# How to use delegates in ios 5

Tags: ios5, delegates

I need to use a delegate object in an iOS application. I have declared the delegate as this:

In the class where the function is defined:

```
@interface OOObjectCommandInterface : NSObject<OOCameraControllerDelegate>
```

In the class where the function must be invoqued:
(In de .h file)

```
@protocol OOCameraControllerDelegate

- (void)drawFrame:(CVImageBufferRef) imageBuffer:(BOOL)flip;

@end
```

and

```
@interface OOCameraController : UIViewController
{
    ...    
    id<OOCameraControllerDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) id<OOCameraControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

Aditionally, where the second class is initialized:

```
_hardwareController.delegate = [OOObjectCommandInterface ocInterface];
```

where `_hardwareController` is an instance of `OOCameraController` class. 
So, when I try to invoque the delegate object, I do this:

```
[delegate drawFrame:imageBuffer:flip];
```

but the function is not executed. Any idea?

P.D.: The function I am calling is a singleton class. Could be any problem there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, a singleton is a design patron to access an object, unique, that only can be created 1 time (first get_instance you do). With get_instance, you can access from everywhere, to the functions inside the singleton, so, Why you are not using it directly?

Write something like [[MySingletonClass get_instance] FunctionThatIWantToUse:...]; And don't use a delegate

Answer (score 4):

Have you set delegate to self in the second class? Create an object in the second class like

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) id<OOCameraControllerDelegate> delegate;
```

and then `[_hardwareController setDelegate:self];`